# Nested for loop array initialization

Tags: objective-c

I want to initialize a 2-d array `gameBoard` and display the result on screen. Will the following nested for loops work? I'm having trouble displaying it on the screen so I can't tell if this is working correctly or not.

```
for (NSInteger x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
{
    for (NSInteger y = 0; y <=2; y++)
    {
        gameBoard [x][y] = 0;
        NSLog(@"%ld"), gameBoard [x][y];
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is going to log column-major. Generally you want the row loop (y) to be the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NSLog` line is wrong, but other than that you're ok (assuming your array is appropriately sized, that is).  Change the log line to:

```
NSLog(@"%ld", gameBoard[x][y]);
```

to get some actual output.  Now that I look again, I think your example won't even compile cleanly the way it is.

Comment: Ops I should have realized my parenthesis mistake. Yeah I was getting an error but it was compiling something crazy ha